# extract first not-null key-value pair in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's assume I have the following object:

```js
const obj = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: 1
}
```

What I want to extract is the first not-null pair, here `{c: 1}`?

My current attempt works but is hardcoded and not dynamic:

```js
const data = obj.a ? {a: obj.a} : (obj.b ? {b: obj.b} : {c: obj.c})
```

Comment: Using object property order is typically not a good idea (confusing for people who don't fully know how it works, and others tend to just not use it at all). I therefore am a bit stuck on the "first" part, more than the actual problem. From your hardcoded attempt, is the order of properties custom-defined, and not ES2020 property order? I mean, you could do `Object.entries(obj).find(([, v]) => v !== null)`, but i fear the "order" you'll get might not be completely clear (also note you'll need to wrap it with `Object.fromEntries`, but error handling when there is another problem).

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for that note, but in my usecase there are only two cases:
- only one value given
- multiple values, all refer to unique columns in a db so it doesn't matter which one is picked

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys of the object. Then, use `find` to return the first key with a non-null value.

```js
const obj = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: 1
}

const keyWithValue = Object.keys(obj).find((key) => obj[key] !== null);

return { [keyWithValue]: obj[keyWithValue] };
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```js
const obj = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: 1
}
const data = {}

for(let key in obj) {
  if(obj[key]) data[key] = obj[key]
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the object keys and use break to stop the loop once you find the first value which is not null.
Perhaps, something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: 1
}

let notNullValue;
for(let prop in obj) {
  if(obj[prop] !== null){
    notNullValue = {[prop]: obj[prop]};
    break;
  }
}

console.log(notNullValue);
```